# Query filter assign sub query to one field value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have stuck in this issue from the last two days.

Please help.

I want to assign the following query .

```
$qr = "( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = 'node' AND subconfigcode.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('offering')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)";
```

to

one view's field value.

I have used the following code.

```
 function general_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
        $qr = " ( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = 'node' AND subconfigcode.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('offering')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)";

        $query->add_where(1, "node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value",  $qr);

    }
```

But, it is returning the following where query.

```
where node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value = '( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = \'node\' AND subconfigcode.deleted = \'0\') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = \'1\') AND (node.type IN  (\'offering\')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) ')
```

I want to get query without the single quote assigned for sub query and remove extra slashed added to each value.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

Direct query is not applicable for assignment purpose in the add_where condition.

For that, I have generated the query object using.

```
function general_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
                   $subQuery = db_select('node', 'node'); $subQuery->leftJoin('field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio', 'select_parent_configuratio ', 'node.nid = select_parent_configuratio .entity_id');
                   $subQuery->condition('select_parent_configuratio.entity_type', 'node', '=');
                   $subQuery->condition('select_parent_configuratio.deleted', '0', '=');
                   $subQuery->leftJoin('node', 'select_parent_configuratio_node',  'select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid  = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid');   
                   $subQuery->leftJoin('field_data_field_subconfigcode', 'subconfigcode',  'select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id');    
                   $subQuery->condition('subconfigcode.entity_type', 'node', '=');
                   $subQuery->condition('subconfigcode.deleted', '0', '=');  
                   $subQuery->where("select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid");  
                   $subQuery->condition('node.status', "1", '=');  
                   $subQuery->condition('node.type', array('offering'), 'IN');  
                   $subQuery->orderBy('configcode');
                   $subQuery->addField('subconfigcode', 'field_subconfigcode_value', 'configcode');
                   //$subQuery->range(0, 1);
                   $query->add_where($group,'node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value',$subQuery,'in');
}
```

Using this, I am able to generate it the query and assignment to value of the variable.